# autoexpect on docker centos6.6 container cannot work

Tags: centos, docker, expect, autoexpect

Docker container 
pure image: centos6.6
after bash, I install these:
yum -y install tar zip unzip expect glibc.i686

Package expect-5.44.1.15-5.el6_4.x86_64 already installed and latest version

and run autoexpect, I always get these error:

```
[root@179314389a2c bin]# autoexpect
autoexpect started, file is script.exp
no such variable
    (read trace on "env(SHELL)")
    invoked from within
"spawn -noecho $env(SHELL)"
    invoked from within
"if {[llength $argv]>0} {
        eval spawn -noecho $argv
        cmd "spawn $argv"
} else {
        spawn -noecho $env(SHELL)
        cmd "spawn \$env(SHELL)"
}"
    (file "/usr/bin/autoexpect" line 315)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `autoexpect` requires the `SHELL` env var be set but your current running shell (not `bash`?) does not set it. So try `SHELL=bash autoexpect`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the job!